# Referencing jre7

Tags: windows, java-7

I am running Eclipse on my USB memory. I need to use jre 7. I can't install JRE 7 on my public computer. It has got only JRE 6. How can I reference JRE 7?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a machine you control, download the latest JRE from Oracle (or the vendor of your choice) and install it.  Once it is installed, copy the `c:\Program Files\Java` folder to your USB stick.  Once you've copied the files over, you can uninstall Java if you want.

You should then be able to point Eclipse to the instance of Java on the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, click on:

```
 window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs 
 click on Add
 select standard VM -> Next
 click on Directory... -> select the location of your jdk 7
 click on Finish -> ok
```

Comment: I have tried this before. At the place of directory it expects the directory of installed JRE. In my case I either got jar or exe files of jre. Both are hidden.

Comment: thats because you have to point to the installation directory of your jre or jdk and not an exe or jar file. You have to install the jdk on your usb stick before proceeding.